# loading a class from out of classpath by using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, classpath

I want to load class from that is not in class path.
is there any way that I load class by file path without being in classpath ?
for example

```
ClassLoader.load("c:\MyClass.class");
```

Answer (score 7):

Example taken from [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/LoadClass.html):

```
// Create a File object on the root of the directory containing the class file  
File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Load your class content into a byte array and use [ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) manually.

Comment: You have to load any dependencies manually as well.  An alternative is to create a new URLClassLoader which includes your desired class.

Comment: I want to load all classes in a package that depend on each other. can I load classes in this way ?