# Catch exceptions by calling another java program

Tags: java, reflection, exception

I have around 20 Java programs each containing a main() function. I want to call all of them and check for an exception.

Is there a way to call a java program from another java program and also get the exceptions returned ?

Comment: Perhaps something hacky using a ClassLoader. Only alternative I can think of is `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` but that won't let you catch exceptions outside of parsing the output.

Comment: You can call `main` from another class.  It's just a method.  Do `java MyDriverClass` and have MyDriverClass call the `main` methods of the other classes (and catch exceptions as desired).

Comment: @ Rogue and Hot Licks, I think you should put these as answers instead. ;)

Comment: You can use reflection provided your main method does not explicitly throw ReflectionExceptions such IllegalAccessException or .However,you may need to modify your code if  your main method chooses to throw such exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[]){
     try{
       AnotherClass.main(null); // null inserted for string[] args in the AnotherClass.main
     catch(Exception ex){
       //do whatever you want
     }
  }
}
```

call the Main class with

```
java Main
```

It will run the AnotherClass main and you can catch the exception.

Comment: how do I iterate over a list of classes instead of manually adding them to the driver file, given that my classes are in com.xyz.AnotherClass1, com.xyx.anotherxlass2 etc ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926144/loading-a-class-from-out-of-classpath-by-using-java-reflection
is a good start up. it will load the class using a class loader.
then you can use reflection to call the main method. of each class.

Comment: This does not answer for 20 different classes.The user would have to explicitly invoke all the classes main method

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection.
Just have all the class names in a file or dataBase and then use the following steps

```
 List<String> listOfJavaFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    //
    listofJavaFiles.add("package.className");
    ---
    //
    for(String fileName = listOfJavaFiles){
    Class<?> cl = Class.forName(fileName );

Method mh = null;
        try {
            mh = cl.getMethod("main",String[].class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {


        } catch (SecurityException se) {

        }
        if(mh!=null){


            try {
                mh.invoke(null,(Object)new String[0]);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {


            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {


            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {


            }catch(Exception e){
            //your logic should go here
                    ////The exception will get thrown here for your main program       provided your main program does not throw IllegalAccessException ,IllegalArgumentException and InvocationTargetException 
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: @AdamGent True but he will have to write 20 metthod invocations for 20 different classes.With a single method ,you can iterate and invoke the main methods of all these classes

Comment: I suppose. I am not entirely sure now what the OP was asking or his intentions. So you can ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly call all the static `main`s from a parent class (with or with out reflection) I highly recommend you refactor your code and make all those classes implement an interface.

```
public interface CustomMain {
  public void doMain(String args[]);
} 

public class OneOfTheMainClasses implements CustomMain {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new OneOfTheMainClasses().doMain(args); // for backward compat.
  }
  public void doMain(String args[]) { //work here }
}
```

Then in your code you will create each one of the classes that has a `main` and implements `CustomMain` and put them in a `List<CustomMain>`.

```
List<CustomMain> mains = ...; //(Either use reflection or manually add the instances)
for (CustomMain m : mains) {
  try {
    m.doMain(args);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // do what you want here.
  }
}
```

One big reason why you should refactor... the `static main` has an implicit contract in that is the entry point and **exit point**. That is a `static main` may call `System.exit(0)` or various other exit procedures

Comment: Cant we call System.exit(0) from anywhere in the program?